# Delphi D2010 Component Palette icons all wrong

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

I have just built a new system.  (Win 8.1, 64 bit, D2010).  Install went fine... adding some various VCLs.  For some reason, in the Delphi Component Palette, all component glyphs PAST the 'Gestures' palette are all defaulting to the 'generic' icon.  The first 13 tabsheets use proper icons.  The remaining 30 or so tabsheets use the generic 'Blue box, red triangle, gold circle' image.

Delphi compiles my apps fine.  For some reason the GLYPHs are just messed up.  I have exited Delphi, restarted, even rebooted the machine.  It was initially working fine, but then it messed up.  So what did I do?  I installed a few components, which I have installed before...  I added some help files to the Windows help system for one of the components.  I added some directories to the Delphi Path, and added a new BPL file for some of the components, and I went into the Tool/Options/Component Tool Bar and moved one component from a page by itself to another page.  This left an empty page/tabsheet, so I deleted it. Thinking this might be the problem, I went back in and clicked on 'Reset to Default'. It did reset the one component back to a page by itself.   Restarted Delphi... same issue.

UPDATED INFO***:  Some Embarcadero supplied pages show fine, others show 'Unknown/Default' Glyph.  For example, the first 13 pages are good, then are 10 or so pages bad, then SAMPLES, INTERNET, and few others are good. Pages that are bad include INDY (the whole set) and IW (the whole set). All my TMS stuff is good (which I installed).  Some of the JVCL pages are good, some are bad.  Interestingly, one page, Jv Edits, is half bad, then the rest of the page is good.

Comment: there is (still) no such thing as a VCL. What you mean is a VCL component.

Comment: Are the problem components built in, or the ones that you have compiled?

Comment: Updated initial question with new data...

Comment: Are you using the "Classic Undocked" IDE layout, or one the more modern (VS-like) embedded layouts? (The default embedded layout doesn't have component "tabs", but uses a more `TCategoryButtons` type tree-type layout where categories can be expanded/collapsed.)

Comment: I am using the Classic Undocked layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I switched back and forth to different IDE Layouts (Default Layout, Classic Undocked, etc) a few times, the palette glyphs got reloaded, and now everything looks as it should.